# Magento 2 How to get custom category attribute on frontend

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

I have created a new category attribute using a setup script and now it is showing on the backend and assigned values (it is just a boolean attribute). the attribute name on EAV entity table is `is_home_category` .And now I'm trying to get its values on frontend

```
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true, true, true);

foreach ($categories as $category):
   echo $category->getIsHomeCategory()
endforeach;
```

But it returns nothing , could someone help me

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution thanks

Answer (score 8):

Proper way is to in the Install/Upgrade script:

```php
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
    'my_custom_attribute',
    [
        // ...
        'used_in_product_listing' => true, // for category pages
        'visible_on_front' => true, // for frontend??
        'is_used_in_grid' => true, // for category pages
        'is_visible_in_grid' => true // for category pages
    ]
);
```

also on the collection do:

```php
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('my_custom_attribute')
```

and then in the template you can just call:

```php
$category->getMyCustomAttribute()
// or
$category->getData('my_custom_attribute');
```

If still not work run below command:

```php
php bin/magento in:reindex
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'also on the collection do'

Comment: Also when i try to use this in my phtml fille it just says that $category is undefined

Comment: I have set the visible_on_front as true, but still, in front-end, the value has not shown, but if I used the registry('current_category') the custom attribute has listing

Comment: Hello I did this, I see my value in the database but i cannot get the value on a frontend block, i even try using a helper but is not working

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers are correct **only** if you explicitly indicates which attributes you want with `addAttributeToSelect('is_home_category')` or `addAttributeToFilter('is_home_category')` but this has limitations.

If you want your attribute to be always loaded with `addAttributeTSelect('*')`, you **also** have to create a new file `etc/catalog_attributes.xml` in your module and put the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="catalog_category">
        <attribute name="is_home_category"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Then flush your caches and now every new category collection with `addAttributeToSelect('*')` will contains the field `is_home_category` if the category has a value for this attribute.

Note that this XML file can also contains data for other type of entites like products, you can see a lot of its usages if your search in Magento's core modules.

Answer (score 0):

In your extension you should override the Category model (which contains all the data) and add a method to obtain the new attribute. In this way you can get the data in your view.

So first you have to create a file `app\code\VENDOR\EXTENSION-NAME\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="VENDOR\EXTENSION-NAME\Model\Category" />
</config>
```

If you already have this file, just add the `<preference>` tag.

Create the `Category.php` file in `app\code\VENDOR\EXTENSION-NAME\Model\`. This file should contain the following (or something like it):

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\EXTENSION-NAME\Model;

class Category extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
{
    public function getIsHomeCategory()
    {            
        return $this->getCustomAttribute('is_home_category');            
    }
}
```

Flush your cache, and now you should be able to call this `getIsHomeCategory` function.

Comment: I think we should not override core functions

Comment: Since `getIsHomeCategory` isn't a core function this is not the case.

Comment: no I mean Magento\Catalog\Model\Category class

Comment: I think it is the only way to achieve this. A plugin (interceptor) can only hook into existing (public) functions. Also, this is the way Magento does it. For example take a look at module-catalog-search/etc/di.xml. Here the SearchCollectionInterface is overwritten. When you check the class in this module you will see it extends the original one. 

(Maybe one improvement may be to prefer an interface instead of a class. But the idea remains the same)

Comment: There is absolutely no point for doing it. It will impact performance heavily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$categoryId = 3;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
echo $category->getName();
echo $category->getData('<attribute_code>');
```

Or you can do this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
protected $_categoryFactory;    

public function __construct(
\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
) {
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCategoryData($attrCode)
{
    $categoryId = '43';
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $categoryAttributeName = $category->getData($attrCode);
    return $categoryName;
}
}
```

Comment: Here it should be 
return $categoryAttributeName;