# Magento2.1 - Show custom category attribute on frontend

Tags: category, magento-2.1, custom-attributes

I added a custom category attribute via a module as [this tutorial](https://gielberkers.com/adding-custom-category-attributes-magento-2-1/) shows, that's working fine; the field is shown and saved correctly in the backend. But I can't figure out how to show it on the frontend.

I've added the attribute as a textfield, and it's content is supposed to be shown in a custom .phtml block that gets loaded on the category-view via XML.

I first tried to do it like you'd call a product attribute, i.e.

```
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_category = $block->getCategory();
echo $_category->getData('customcatattribute');
```

But no luck.

Then I found [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/113916/37536) and applied what it says, but still no luck.

Whenever I try to call the field I either get no results and the page works, or the page breaks and stays blank.

This shouldn't be too hard, how can I call my custom category attribute?

Comment: Hey @Alex..did you found any solution for this?...If yes, then let me know please...

Comment: Hey @Yudi - I eventually got it to work. I'm not too sure if I fixed something or that it was a bug in Magento that got fixed. Either way, I'll dig up my working code and add it as an answer in a moment!

Comment: Thanks for quick response. and i am waiting for the answer....:)

Comment: @Yudi ; did you get the module working, or do you need the layout of that aswell?

Comment: I created my custom module. Only i just want to render the data in front-end. So i am asking just for the code by which i can render the data in my product listing page.

Comment: For more info let me tell you that i have created custom attribute for category. In which i want to show some details about the category. The data is saving in backend. Only want to show in frontend also.

Comment: And if you can share the module also then it'll be vary helpful for the community. we can more elaborate the idea...

Comment: @Yudi I added the code and module below!

Comment: @Alex..I tried also like this. but nothing showing in frontend. also tried to install your's module, but it giving warning message that "Vendor_CatAtt data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.2". :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50191/discussion-between-alex-timmer-and-yudi).

Comment: @Alex...Dude...Its working now....
The foult was only version..when i changed its version to 2.0.1 its started working. Thanks
Cheers...

Comment: Cheers mate, I updated the module on Github. Looks like we saved eachothers asses ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I was able to call the custom attribute in the frontend (in my case an extra category-image) like this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
$catbgimg = $category->getData('cat_bgimg');

if (!empty($catbgimg)) {
    echo '<img src="' . $catbgimg . '" />';
} else {
    // Something else
}
```

I know calling the `objectManager` directly is shunned, but whatever works. If anyone has a better idea, I'd love to hear :)

Edit: I added the module to GitHub: https://github.com/Asitis/m2-CatAtt

Comment: Does that work with flat tables enabled and disabled?, Don't think so

Answer (score 0):

```
$category_id = 20;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category_id);  
print($_category->getData('custom_attribute'));
```