# Get custom category attribute value in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

How will I get the custom created category attribute value on the product list page?

I have seen many answers but no one is working.

Comment: where you want to add custom attribute value on list page what type of value it. is text or select

Comment: Add code here, which you already tried

Comment: @RohanHapani I have tried from here all answers https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95563/magento-2-how-to-get-custom-category-attribute-on-frontend

Comment: @AmanAlam it is a text value

Comment: You can accept and upvote if it's helpful for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get value from current category data. Try this below code :

```
protected $_categoryFactory;
protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    ....
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $current_cat_id = $this->_registry->registry('current_category')->getId();
    $categoryData = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($current_cat_id);
    $getContent = $categoryData->getData('is_home_page'); //is_home_page = your attribute code
    echo $getContent;
}
```

Comment: This one is not working.

Comment: Is any error or system.log?

Comment: I have used catalog_category_entity_varchar directly to get the values using attribute id.

Comment: @AmritPalSingh can you share your code?