# get Custom attributes category Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, category-attribute

after add new custom attribute, i am trying to get my custom attribute category, filter by the parent id, actually it return me a null value or empty array I used `$category->getData('label_text')`, `$category->getLabelText()`, `$category->getCustomAttribute('label_text')`... 
Do i have to join catalog_category_varchar and eav_attribute to reach it ? If someone of you have some advices.
thanks

Comment: how are you getting your `$category` instance?

Comment: with $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($entityId);

Comment: Please check your attribute's options. It must be visible on frontend otherwise will not be included in collection.

Answer (score 0):

`Install/Upgrade` script:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'my_custom_attribute',
        [
            // ...
            'used_in_product_listing' => true, // for category pages
            'visible_on_front' => true, // for frontend??
            'is_used_in_grid' => true, // for category pages
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true // for category pages
        ]
    );
```

also on the collection do:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('my_custom_attribute')
```

and then in the template you can just call:

```
$category->getMyCustomAttribute()
// or
$category->getData('my_custom_attribute');
```

If still not work run below command:

```
php bin/magento in:reindex
```

And more information this link ---

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/184453/85907**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...