# Magento2 : Custom Category Attribute Not Showing on Frontend

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

I've create a module to add a custom attribute to my categories, however my code doesn't seem to be display the attribute on frontend. i dont know where i am wrong.

app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
 use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'attribute_code',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Attribute Label',
            'input' => 'select',
            'sort_order' => 333,
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'group' => 'General Information'
        ]
    );
}
}
```

/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="general">
    <field name="attribute_code" sortOrder="20" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>boolean</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Attribute Label</label>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="string">0</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="string">1</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: With this file  /app/code/view/adminhtml/ui_component   "adminhtml" scope it should be in admin side.

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal Thank you for reply, but i didn't get you.

Comment: @FenaShah What he is trying to explain is that your category_form.xml

 only add the field in the admin part. If you want to add this field in front you need extra modification depending on what you try to do.

Comment: @Claims ohh got it. but attribute is saving value in database so i can get it in category collection on frontend.

Comment: Depending on where you want in the frontend it will always be possible to get the attribute value indeed. Usually you have a magical setter / getter on your attribute depending on it's code. `$category->getMyOwnCustomAttributeCodeInCategory()`

Answer (score 1):

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup**

**InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.1', '<=')) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

                $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                    'is_enable_attribute11',
                        [
                            'type'     => 'int',
                            'label'    => 'Display Category in Homepage',
                            'input'    => 'Boolean',
                            'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                            'visible'  => true,
                            'required' => false,
                            'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                            'group' => 'General Information',
                           
                        ]
                );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="is_enable_attribute11">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Display Category in Homepage</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                        <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                        </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> **Try to get value from it like this**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Categoryimage extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_categoryNameFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryNameFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collecionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryNameFactory = $categoryNameFactory;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $collecionFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getEnableCategory()
    {
        // this return all category with enable attribute values
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('is_enable_attribute11',1)->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
        return $category;
    }

    public function getCategoryName($categoryId)
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryNameFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
        //$categoryName = $category->getName();
        return $category;
    }
}
```

> Also try this to get values from collection

```
$category->getMyCustomAttribute()
// or
$category->getData('my_custom_attribute');
// or
$category->addAttributeToSelect('my_custom_attribute')
```

Comment: get custom attribute value from this link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95563/magento-2-how-to-get-custom-category-attribute-on-frontend

Answer (score 1):

> `Add the Below code in your block class`

```
<?php 
    
 namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

  class CategoryCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
       
    protected $categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    )

    {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCategoryAttribute($id){
        return $this->categoryRepository->get($id);
    }
     
  }
```

> `Add the Below Code in your phtml file`

```
<?php

    /**
     *
     * @var $block \vendor\Module\Block\CategoryCollection 
     */
     
  $id = 10; //your category id.
  
    
 $customAttribute= $block->getCategoryAttribute($id);
 echo $customAttribute->getData('attribute_code');

?>
```